# Javascript not working for checkboxes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, checkbox, console

I have a set of checkboxes in my site that run the javascript posted below. The issue is that when I pick a color from the checkboxes, it does not do any action and I see the following error in the Chrome console:

```
GET ../store/indexMain.php?color=Khaki 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
send jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
f.fn.extend.load jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
(anonymous function) www.tahara.es:68
f.event.dispatch jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
h.handle.i
```

Here is the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //http://jsbin.com/ujuse/1/edit
$(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
        var boxes = [];
        // You could save a little time and space by doing this:
        var name = this.name;
        // critical change on next line
        $("input[type='checkbox'][name='"+this.name+"']:checked").each(function() {
            boxes.push(this.value);
        });
        if (boxes.length) {
            $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300);
            // Change the name here as well
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?'+this.name+'=' + boxes.join("+"),
            function() {
                $(".indexMain").fadeIn('slow');
                $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
            });

        } else {
            $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300);
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php', function() {
                $(".indexMain").fadeIn('slow');
                $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Adding PHP from indexMain.php

```
<?php
$colors = $_GET['color'];
if ($colors != '')
 {
            $colors = explode(' ', $colors);
            $parameters = join(', ', array_fill(0, count($colors), '?'));
            $items = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 IN ({$parameters})");
            $items ->execute($colors);
            $count = $items -> rowCount();

}
else 
{

        $items = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr ORDER BY date DESC");
        $items -> execute();
        $count = $items -> rowCount();


}

$row_count = 0;
echo "<div>Showing ".$count."items</div>";
while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `500 (Internal Server Error)`

There is a problem in the php script you are `GETTING` at /store/indexMain.php?color=Khaki   --   Have you tried just going to the URL and see what happens?

Comment: Could you possibly go and set some of your 19 outstanding questions to answered?

Comment: @Zak - I posted the PHP part... would you mind taking a look?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the javascript, but rather in your server side.

```
$(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?'+this.name+'=' + boxes.join("+"), function() {
    $(".indexMain").fadeIn('slow');
    $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
});
```

You tried to load something from the server, and the server respond with 500. Check your server log and see what's the problem

Comment: I just posted the PHP part... I can't find the issue

Comment: You need to check the server side log, because you get http 500 error, which is always triggered due to kind of server fail, e.g. error to access a database, or some program logic error caused exception

Comment: How can i check that log from Chrome?

Comment: you can't check server log from front end. You need to go to where indexMain.php is running and check the log on the console of that machine